# Using an inputted char as the variable name for a class object

Tags: java, variables

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import java.awt.*;

public class PracDriver  {

public static void main ( String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{      
    DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(600, 600);
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    Picture pic1 = new Picture<>();



    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    String filename = read.nextLine();
    File file = new File(filename);
    System.out.println(filename);
    read.close();
    Scanner in = new Scanner("start picture A");
    in.useDelimiter(" ");

    while(in.hasNextLine()){

        String token1 = in.next();
        if (token1.equalsIgnoreCase("start")){
           System.out.println("john");
           String token2 = in.next();
           if(token2.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")){
               System.out.println("doe");
               char t = in.next().charAt(0);
               Picture t = new Picture();
           }
           else{
               System.out.println("Improper imput from file");
           }
        }
        else if (token1.equalsIgnoreCase("end")){
            System.out.println("john");
            String token2 = in.next();
            if(token2.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")){
                System.out.println("doe");
             }
        }
        else if(token1.equalsIgnoreCase("erase")){
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else if(token1.equalsIgnoreCase("cirlce")){
            int token2 = in.nextInt();
            int token3 = in.nextInt();
            int token4 = in.nextInt();
            Circle circ = new Circle("circ", token2, token3, token4);
            pic1.addShape(circ);
        }
```

So, in my Scanner in I have some testing code(it's supposed to read from a file but that's not important) that reads "start picture A". I have a delimiter so it reads each string seperately. It takes in the 'start' and 'picture' part and seems to work fine. The problem is that my Picture has to be named after the char after "start picture", which in this case is A. So I need to take in the input for that char, and then name my Picture variable after it. So in this case, i would need the Picture to be called Picture A = new Picture();. The problem is that I don't know how to do that. I can't convert the char to my Picture class object. Another problem is that that rest of my if else statements need to use the new Picture too(Picture A in this case) to add the Shapes(my class) in. But that won't work a local variable. I'd appreciate any help. Also ignore the Picture p1. It needs to be removed or replaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible. However, there are serious design decisions that you're making that render what you're trying to do somewhat irrelevant, since there are other methods you can use to accomplish what you want.

First thing: your code, all variables, and anything you put in your source files that are supposed to be known at the time you compile are called "compile time" dependencies or references.
These are things that the java compiler will require you to specify before anyone can even run the program.
Variable names are included in this list of things (going further into detail would be attempting to teach basic Java, so I won't do that here...)

Anything you need your code to do based on user input are called "runtime" dependencies or references. User input at the command line, files loaded from the file system, UI events, etc. are all examples of where you might construct your compiled code to handle these unknown-at-compile-time items (hence, runtime).

If you need to identify your objects based on some user input, declare a method in your class for which you can use to assign the user input value and create your desired mapping.
Use of a `Map` is another means you can associate objects with keys (key/value pairs) and accomplish what you're trying to do.

Example:

```
public class Picture {
    private String name;
    // other properties omitted for clarity
    public Picture() {
        this.name = "some default";
    }

    // use getters/setters to access and assign object data, which can include
    // user-input obtained at runtime
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

and in your code, you can make use of this by doing something similar to what you have:

```
if (token1.equalsIgnoreCase("start")){
    System.out.println("john");
    String token2 = in.next();
    if(token2.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")){
        System.out.println("doe");
        char inputChar = in.next().charAt(0);  // use a more descriptive name...
        Picture picture = new Picture();
        picture.setName(Character.toString(inputChar)); // note the "generic" name for this picture object variable. The runtime information is stored in the object as a property.
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Improper imput from file");
    }
}
```

The important takeaway here would be to note that the variable name used to refer to an object should have no bearing on what you intend to do with the program when it's run, it's meant for use in identifying purpose and scope during development.

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking, is not what you actually want to achieve.

```
Picture A =       new Picture()
^       ^             ^
|       |             |
Class   Variable      Object
```

You want the `new Picture()` object to be called `A`. But `A` is the variable name, so that the java compiler and runtime know what memory address to access the `new Picture()` object.  This is not the name of the object or an indication of the data associated with the object.  Typically most classes will define a 'name' property which would be accessed from your object as such (noting I am not sure what the class definition is for your Picture object)

```
Picture pic = new Picture();
pic.setName("A");
```

Also note that in your code:

```
 if(token2.equalsIgnoreCase("picture")){
     System.out.println("doe");
     char t = in.next().charAt(0);
     Picture t = new Picture();
 }
```

you have 2 variables called `t`. These should not be an indication of the value of the object. Again variables are defined so that the compiler and runtime know what object you are talking about.  The first is a char type variable, so call it `c` or `ch`, and the second variable is a Picture type variable so call it `pic` or `picture`.  The naming of variables improves readability for future developers who look at your code.

Also within this block of code, because you define the variables within the block, but do not use them within the block, the compiler will raise a warning telling you that although you have created the variables, they are not referred to later, therefore there is no point in doing this.  **IF** you do try to refer to them later outside of this block, the compiler will raise an error, because variables are out of scope of the block in which they are defined.